# Running a collection of BackgroundWorkers one after the other

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, queue

In my project, I had three `BackgroundWorker`s that can be run independently, but I also wanted to allow the user to "Run All" of them, but not at the same time. They need to be run one after the other. So, I devised this `class` to create a `Queue` of `BackgroundWorker`s, subscribe to their `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler, and run the next worker in the `Queue`.

I would like to know:

1. If this is even a good idea
2. If there are any potential bugs I might have overlooked
3. If I've violated any normal .Net conventions.
4. Any ways to improve the functionality, speed, or readability of the code

```
/// <summary>
/// Simplifies running a Queue of BackgroundWorkers one after the other without blocking the current thread. 
/// </summary>
public class BackgroundWorkerQueue
{
    /// <summary>Continue running BackgroundWorkerQueue if any BackgroundWorker causes an Exception.</summary>
    public bool ContinueOnError { get; set; }
    private Queue<QueuedWorker> Queue { get; set; }
    public BackgroundWorkerQueue( )
    {
        this.Queue = new Queue<QueuedWorker>();
    }
    public static BackgroundWorkerQueue operator +( BackgroundWorkerQueue left, BackgroundWorker worker )
    {
        left.Add(worker);
        return left;
    }
    public static BackgroundWorkerQueue operator +( BackgroundWorkerQueue left, QueuedWorker worker )
    {
        left.Add(worker);
        return left;
    }
    /// <summary>Add a BackgroundWorker to the Queue</summary>
    /// <param name="worker">BackgroundWorker to call RunWorkerAsync() on.</param>
    /// <param name="argument">A parameter for use by the background operation to be executed in the System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.DoWork event handler.</param>
    public void Add( BackgroundWorker worker, object argument )
    {
        this.Queue.Enqueue(new QueuedWorker(worker,argument));
    }
    /// <summary>Add a BackgroundWorker to the Queue</summary>
    /// <param name="worker">BackgroundWorker to call RunWorkerAsync() on.</param>
    public void Add( BackgroundWorker worker )
    {
        this.Queue.Enqueue(new QueuedWorker(worker,null));
    }
    /// <summary>Add a BackgroundWorker to the Queue</summary>
    public void Add( QueuedWorker worker )
    {
        this.Queue.Enqueue(worker);
    }
    /// <summary>Starts execution of the BackgroundWorkers.</summary>
    public void Run( )
    {
        Debug.Print("BackgroundWorkerQueue.Run(), {0} items in queue.", this.Queue.Count);
        QueuedWorker q = this.Queue.Dequeue();
        q.Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.Completed);
        q.Worker.RunWorkerAsync(q.Argument);
    }
    private void Completed( object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
    {
        Debug.Print("BackgroundWorkerQueue.Completed()");
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        if( worker != null )
        {
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted -= this.Completed; // Unsubscribe to event
            if( (this.ContinueOnError || e.Error == null) && this.Queue.Count > 0 )
                this.Run(); // Run the next worker. 
        }
    }
    /// <summary>Object containing a BackgroundWorker and optional Argument to be run.</summary>
    public class QueuedWorker
    {
        /// <summary></summary>A parameter for use by the background operation to be executed in the System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.DoWork event handler.</summary>
        public object Argument { get; set; }
        /// <summary>BackgroundWorker to be run.</summary>
        public BackgroundWorker Worker { get; set; }
        public QueuedWorker()
        {
        }
        /// <param name="worker">BackgroundWorker to call RunWorkerAsync() on.</param>
        /// <param name="argument">A parameter for use by the background operation to be executed in the System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.DoWork event handler.</param>
        public QueuedWorker( BackgroundWorker worker, object argument )
        {
            this.Worker = worker;
            this.Argument = argument;
        }
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
var q = new BackgroundWorkerQueue();
q.Add(InventoryBgWorker,"FIN STOCK"); // to add a worker, you can call one of the Add(...) methods
q += PartDataBgWorker;                // or you can use the += operator
q += OpenOrdersBgWorker;
q.Run(); // Does not block current thread.
```

Comment: You could consider creating class that converts/wraps the background workers using TPL (Task / TaskCompletionSource) and then await the workers. `Task.WhenAll` can also be used to run them simultaneously.

Comment: Or foregoing the background workers altogether and use Tasks https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-1.html and https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html

Answer (score 4):

You can forego the background workers in favor of Tasks either via `Task.Run` or just async functions. They can be run independently, all at once or sequentially.

The following example takes a collection of tasks and invokes them one after the other.

```
//Assuming all the following return Task derived results
var tasks = new Func<Task>[] {
  () => InventoryService.GetInventoryAsync("FIN STOCK"),
  () => PartsService.GetPartDataAsync(),
  () => OrdersService.OpenOrderAsync()
};

Debug.Print("RunAllAsync(), {0} items in collection.", tasks.Length);
foreach (var task in tasks) {
    try {
        await task();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (ContinueOnError)
            continue;
        else
            break;
    }
}
```